# prevent users from zoom in and out in safari desktop browswer

Tags: html, safari

I am on Safari 14 on laptop. I saw many solutions tailured towards the mobile safari that didn't work for me. Tried

```
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

But still users can zoom in on the page.